# Java script addition of numbers with giving wrong answer

Tags: javascript

I am working with a simple java script code which goes here

```
<script>
var x=prompt("Enter a number");
var n=x+2;
alert(n);
</scrip>
```

This code will throws a prompt If i enter 2 in the prompt.I am expecting output as 4,But it is generating 22 in alert. What mistake is happening here.

Comment: Because user enter a **string** and your number will be converted to string. Try enter "18" and you'll see "182". Check parseInt() on MDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
 var n;
 if(!isNaN(x)) {
    n = parseInt(x) + 2; // make sure x is always a number here
 }
```

This is because the `prompt` function will return an `String`, not a number.

`String` + `Number` = `String`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var x=prompt("Enter a number");
var n=parseInt(x)+2;
alert(n);
</scrip>
```

Comment: Instead of showing a correct answer, you could better describe what was going wrong in the code used by the person who asked the question.

Comment: All you would need to do to make this better is give a nod to the comment from @adrianorepetti

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
var x = prompt("Enter a number");
var n = parseInt(x)+2;
alert(n);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an alternative way of doing this:

```
var x = +prompt("Enter a number");
var n = x+2;
alert(n);
```

*The plus sign (in front of `prompt`) converts the string to a number.*